# Mailer test fails with Call to a member function getSubject() on null

Tags: symfony, mailer

In a Symfony 5.0.2 project a test of the new Mailer fails with

> Error: Call to a member function getSubject() on null

The email [service](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/service-organization) and [test](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/mailer/unit-test) are based on symfonycast tutorials.

Adding `var_dump($email);` in the service immediately after `$email = ...;` shows `object(Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail)#24 (11) {...`, which says there is a real object created in the service.

services.yaml:

```
    App\Services\EmailerService:
        $mailer: '@mailer'
        $senderAddress: '%app.sender_address%'
```

Service:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Twig\Mime\TemplatedEmail;

class EmailerService
{
    private $mailer;
    private $sender;

    public function __construct($mailer, $senderAddress)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->sender = $senderAddress;
    }

    public function appMailer($mailParams)
    {
        $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
                ->from($this->sender)
                ->to($mailParams['recipient'])
                ->subject($mailParams['subject'])
                ->htmlTemplate($mailParams['view'])
                ->context($mailParams['context']);
        $this->mailer->send($email);
    }
}
```

Test:

```
use App\Services\EmailerService;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use Symfony\Component\Mailer\MailerInterface;

class MailerTest extends TestCase
{
    public function testSimpleMessage()
    {
        $symfonyMailer = $this->createMock(MailerInterface::class);
        $symfonyMailer->expects($this->once())
                ->method('send');

        $mailer = new EmailerService($symfonyMailer, 'admin@bogus.info', 'admin@bogus.info');
        $mailParams = [
            'view' => 'Email/non_user_forgotten_password.html.twig',
            'context' => ['supportEmail' => 'admin@bogus.info'],
            'recipient' => 'bborko@bogus.info',
            'subject' => 'Test message',            
        ];
        $email = $mailer->appMailer($mailParams);

        $this->assertSame('Test message', $email->getSubject());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`appMailer()` must return a `TemplatedEmail` object so you can call `getSubject()` on it. Currently it is returning nothing. Change it to:

```
public function appMailer($mailParams)
{
    $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from($this->sender)
            ->to($mailParams['recipient'])
            ->subject($mailParams['subject'])
            ->htmlTemplate($mailParams['view'])
            ->context($mailParams['context']);
    $this->mailer->send($email);

    return $email; // I added this line. 
}
```

Comment: And here I thought whoever built that service symfonycast video knew something I didn't! Can't believe everything you read. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! It's easy to miss a line. In a case like this what I tend to do it try to "go back steps" from the error. Ie look for where this happens and then work my way back to where the variable is created (in this case)